# c# task does not work any faster

Tags: c#, task

I don't know why the two different ways take almost same time,or I use task in the wrong way?,here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    var list = new List<string>();
    list.Add(string.Empty);
    list.Add(string.Empty);
    list.Add(string.Empty);
    //1st,use select
    result.AddRange(list.Select(ls=>Nothing1000000000));
    //2nd,use tasks
    result.Clear();         
    IEnumerable<Task<string>> tasks =
        list.Select(uri =>                Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(()=>Nothing1000000000));
    result.AddRange(tasks.Select(task => task.Result));
}
public static string Nothing1000000000()
{
    int result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        result += i;
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Because they both execute in single thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `tasks` LINQ query is lazy, each tasks gets created just before you wait on it (calling `.Result`).

Call `ToList` on that query to create all tasks immediately.

Apart from that your approach will work. The program will execute in about 1/Nth of the sequential time on an N-core box.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a completely wrong idea of what a task is and does. They are not used to speed up computations so it's no wonder you aren't seeing any difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a single unit of work - your method Nothing1000...  Moving that unit of work from the apps main thread to another thread does not magically change the amount of time that unit of work takes to execute.
One reason you might move it off the main app thread would be to free up that app thread to do other things while the unit of work was executing.  That might improve the user experience but again it won't change the execution time of the unit of work.
Probably what you are after is to break your unit of work up in to N discrete units of work.  The N units will execute faster than the whole thing on a single thread if you have N processers or processor cores - one Task does 1/N of the work on each of N processors/cores.  However there are better ways to handled common senarious like that within TPL.